# Table padding in td

Tags: html, css, angular-material, slim

[image]
its very weird that i have padding in my td but it was 0 padding at all in my inspect element i see padding when i hover in my td? any idea of this?
its very weird lol.

here's my html

```
table.md-table border="1"
  tr.md-table-content-row ng-repeat="(payroll_type, taxes) in ctrl.table_taxes | groupBy:'payroll_type'"
    td.md-table-content.tax_table
      div.pay-type layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="height:20px;"
        | {{ payroll_type | capitalize }}
        md-button.md-mini.md-primary.md-icon-button.md-mr-0.md-pd-0 ng-show="taxtableform.$visible" ng-click="ctrl.addTaxStatus(taxes)"
          md-icon.material-icons.md-fnt-sz-20 add_circle_outline
          md-tooltip Add Tax Status
      hr
        div.md-ta-c style="height:20px;"
          | Exemption
      hr
        div.md-ta-c style="height:20px;"
          | Status
      hr
        span ng-repeat="(status_name, taxes4) in taxes | groupBy:'payroll_type'"
          div.md-ta-c ng-repeat="tax in taxes4 | unique:'status_name'| orderBy: 'status_name'" style="height:20px;"
            hr
              | {{ tax.status_name }}
    td.md-table-content.tax_table.md-ta-r ng-repeat="(column_no, taxes2) in taxes |  groupBy:'column_no'"
      div.md-ta-c.md-mr-t-1 layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="height:20px;"
        span
          | {{ column_no }}
        md-button.md-mini.md-primary.md-icon-button.md-mr-0.md-pd-0 ng-show="taxtableform.$visible" ng-click="ctrl.removeColumn(taxes2)"
          md-icon.material-icons.md-fnt-sz-20 delete
          md-tooltip Delete Column
      hr
      span ng-repeat="(exemption, taxes3) in taxes2 |  groupBy:'exemption'"
        div.item-wrapper style="height:20px;"
          span ng-hide="taxtableform.$visible" e-style="width:50px;" editable-text="exemption" e-form="taxtableform" onbeforesave="ctrl.exemptionChecker($data, exemption, taxes2)"
            | {{ exemption | number: 2 }}
      hr
      span ng-repeat="(over_percentage, taxes3) in taxes2 |  groupBy:'over_percentage'"
        div.item-wrapper style="height:20px;"
          span ng-hide="taxtableform.$visible" e-style="width:50px;" editable-text="over_percentage" e-form="taxtableform" onbeforesave="ctrl.percentageChecker($data, over_percentage, taxes3)"
            | {{ over_percentage | number: 2 }}
      hr
      span ng-repeat="tax in taxes2 | orderBy:'status_name'"
        hr
          div.item-wrapper style="height:20px;"
            span ng-hide="taxtableform.$visible" e-style="width:50px;" editable-text="tax.amount" e-form="taxtableform" onbeforesave="ctrl.taxAmountChecker($data, tax)"
              | {{ tax.amount }}
```

Answer (score 0):

can u try to add this style at table

```
  border-collapse: collapse;
```

Comment: maybe good to mention on the CSS file? From the looks of the code the OP will have a hard time adding to all tables (if there is more than one)

Comment: agree :) maybe he find the way by myself.